Intuitive difference between complex differentiability and $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ real differentiability
Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ with $g(x,y) = (\operatorname{Re}(f(x+yi)), \operatorname{Im}(f(x+yi))$.
It is a stricter condition to assume that $f$ is complex-differentiable (CD), than to assume that $g$ is real-differentiable (RD). For example, if $f(z)=z^*$, then f is not complex-differentiable but $g$ is real-differentiable.
I understand that algebraically, CD is equivalent to RD together with the cauchy-riemann equations, and why this follows from the formal differentiability condition. But intuitively I don't understand why a function like $f(z)=z^*$ shouldn't be thought to satisfiy the intuitive notion of "differentiability".
By the way this question seems similar, but it is more asking for examples.

@Mark I'm pretty sure that by $z^*$ OP means the complex conjugate.

@Mark not really, it is quite common in physics.

Yes I meant complex conjugate.

Op: you should first compare the notions of complex linearity of a map $T:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ vs real-linearity of a map $\Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}^2$. The point is that complex conjugation is not a complex-linear map (of course because it is conjuagte-linear).

@Mark this only proves that you haven't read enough mathematical books. Either way, it is clear now.

@user56834 In the $\mathbb{R}^2$-sense, it would be differentiable. But $\mathbb{C}$ "prides" itself in having a multiplication, so you want can (and want to) write $\tfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and send $h \rightarrow 0$. If you don't define it that way, $\mathbb{C}$ is no different from $\mathbb{R}^2$. So this is mostly algebraic. But with that definition, holomorphic functions satisfy $\Delta \mathrm{Re}(f) = \Delta \mathrm{Im}(f) = 0$.

It is hard to answer this question without having what your intuitive view of differentiability is. With one in hand, someone could post an answer explaining why it leads to the standard result or pinpoint the contrast with the standard definition of complex differentiability in a clear way.

One intuition is: Complex Differentiability = Real Differentiability + Local Angle Preserving (as long as the derivative $\neq 0$).
This "local angle preserving" is the main point behind the Cauchy-Riemann conditions. Explicitly, if $f = (u, v) : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann: $\partial_x u = \partial_y v, \partial_y u = -\partial_x v$, then the Jacobian of $f$ (considered as $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$) at any point $(x, y)$ is forced to have the form
$$
J_f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} a_{x, y} &-b_{x, y} \\ b_{x, y} &a_{x, y} \end{pmatrix}
$$ If this isn't $0$, it's just a rotation $R(\theta_{x, y}), \theta_{x, y} = \arctan(\frac{b_{x, y}}{a_{x, y}})$ scaled by $s_{x, y} = \sqrt{a_{x, y}^2 + b_{x, y}^2}$.
Thus, if you have two differentiable curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ going through $\gamma_1(0) = \gamma_2(0) = (x, y)$, the angle between their tangents $\gamma_1'(0), \gamma_2'(0)$ is preserved by $f$. Explicitly
\begin{align*}
\langle (f \circ \gamma_1)'(0), (f \circ \gamma_2)'(0) \rangle &= \langle f'(x, y) \gamma_1'(0), f'(x, y) \gamma_2'(0) \rangle \\
&= s_{x, y}^2 \langle R(\theta_{x, y}) \gamma_1'(0), R(\theta_{x, y}) \gamma_2'(0) \rangle \\
&= s_{x, y}^2 \langle \gamma_1'(0), \gamma_2'(0) \rangle \quad (\text{rotations preserve inner products})
\end{align*} which can be easily used to see that angles are preserved:
$$
\frac{\langle (f \circ \gamma_1)'(0), (f \circ \gamma_2)'(0) \rangle}{\|(f \circ \gamma_1)'(0)\|\|(f \circ \gamma_2)'(0)\|} = \frac{\langle \gamma_1'(0), \gamma_2'(0) \rangle}{\|\gamma_1'(0)\| \|\gamma_2'(0)\|} 
$$
For conjugation $f(z) = z^\ast$ this "local angle-preserving" is clearly violated. E.g. if you consider the diagonal line $\gamma_2(t) = (t, t)$ and the horizontal line $\gamma_1(t) = (t, 0)$, the $45$ degree angle between them gets flipped by $f$ in their images.

Great explanation! I’ll add this is also an exercise in Stein Shakarchi for anyone curious
